# Error processing broken class file? while executing lint task in android

Tags: android, gradle, lint

The following error messages occur while executing `lint` task in Android Studio, but the build is successful and apk works fine without any issues.

Please let me know how can I get rid of these error messages.

```
Error processing C:\androidProjects\emcaanda_checkin\sampleapps\testapp\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\a
ppcompat-v7\24.1.1\jars\classes.jar:android\support\v7\widget\ShareActionProvider$ShareMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener.class:
broken class file?
Error processing C:\androidProjects\emcaanda_checkin\sampleapps\testapp\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\a
ppcompat-v7\24.1.1\jars\classes.jar:android\support\v7\widget\SuggestionsAdapter.class: broken class file?
Error processing C:\androidProjects\emcaanda_checkin\sampleapps\testapp\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\a
ppcompat-v7\24.1.1\jars\classes.jar:android\support\v7\widget\SuggestionsAdapter$ChildViewCache.class: broken class file?
Error processing C:\androidProjects\emcaanda_checkin\sampleapps\testapp\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\a
ppcompat-v7\24.1.1\jars\classes.jar:android\support\v7\widget\SwitchCompat.class: broken class file?
....
```

Android Studio Version: 2.2
JDK: 1.8
Gradle version: 2.14.1

cmd: `gradle clean build`

this is not an option as my build is successful.

```
android{
    lintOptions{
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: Any success since then?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue after adding firebase-ref dependency to Android project. The build was success but error messages was still present. To prevent these kind of error messages, i have updated gradle plugin version from 3.1.4 to 3.2.0.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

For answer it is pretty late to write but wish to prevent more suffering for fit cases :)